# how to use the verb "marry" in passive form?

Tags: verbs

I am wondering whether or not you feel any difference between them in meaning, or even if the latter could be correct:

A.Despite being married,...

B.Despite to be married,...

Thanks

Comment: B. doesn't work, but there are more ways to say "marry" in passive - context, please!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the preposition despite in the structure of despite + -ing verb, but you cannot use it in front of the to-infinitive. The OP has used the word married as an adjective in the first phrase in the structure of despite + being + adjective which is also correct.

So the the first phrase (despite being married) is grammatically correct and the second one is not correct.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, what about the link???https://www.google.com/search?q=%22despite+to%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22despite+to+do%22&newwindow=1

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/despite

Comment: @nima Sorry, let me type that comment again because I made a typo.  Your search results are generally false positives.  They don't show that beginning a sentence with *Despite to be married* is grammatical.

Comment: what about this? despite to do so

Comment: @nima I count three examples of "despite to do so" on the page you linked, and all three are errors.  The first is an OCR error (there was a table and the OCR didn't handle it correctly).  The second is ungrammatical English by a non-native speaker.  The third is a writing error (the authors wrote *despite* a second time instead of a word that makes sense like *intention*: "Despite their **intention** to do so".